# Jquery XML retrieve data won't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    url:"list.xml",
    dataType:"xml",
    type:"GET",
    success:function(data){
        $(data).find('City').each(function(){
            var book = $(this);
            var city = book.attr("Heb");
            $("#ll").append(city);          
        })
    }
})      
})
```

ok so after looking for error it seems like the error is on parsing the xml data

my xml looks like this
[This this the XML file](http://img2.timg.co.il/forums/1_102884894.xml)

whats wrong with this file?

Comment: Well, does it display anything? Don't ask us that, but rather clarify if it does in the question!

Comment: ok so I tried to see error and the error says
"parseerror"
looks like my XML file might not be good,
it has like 3k lines but when I delete all and leave just one it seems to be ok.
whats is wrong?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
<City Heb="אבו גוש" En="Abu Ghosh"/>
<City Heb="אבו סנאן" En="Abu Sinan"/>

and like 3k more from this City

Answer (score 0):

There are elements like

```
<City Heb="בני עי"ש" En="Bene Ayish"/>
```

which are probably causing the problem.  You could change the format to

```
<City En="Bene Ayish">בני עי"ש</City>
```